# securing GET requests, is is worth doing if data is not private

Tags: rest, security

So my question is what is the right practise for securing GET HTTP requests. I have a GET endpoint that returns some data.

I have heard many people say GET requests don't need to be protected, Since if the request doesnt return any confidential data. It should be okay.

I wanted to know what the practise was in the industry?

Comment: GET requests can return confidential data. How you need to protect it depends on who's allowed to access the data from the GET request and why.

Comment: What do you mean by "securing" a request anyway?

Comment: @Dai can be via jwt tokens.. any type of security even username/password.. but i was more interested in knowing if protecting your all your service endpoints is needed/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the same ... Already the http requests are not encrypted ... and in GET request it wont make a great difference because in this request you ask for something specific .... if you tried to secure it it would be just a headache since the data is not secured from the first place .

Thank you to verify with me if my respond was helpful